# Calculate gradients of intermediate nodes in tensorflow eager execution

Tags: tensorflow

I use tensorflow eager execution to do the following calculation:

```
y = x^2
z = y + 2.
```

My goal is to calculate dz/dx and dz/dy (the gradients of z over y and z)

```
dx, dy = GradientTape.gradient(z, [x, y]).
```

However, only dy is calculated and dx is None. Namely, only the gradients of tensors that directly rely on z can be calculated.

```
[None, <tf.Tensor: id=11, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>]
[None, <tf.Tensor: id=11, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>]
[None, <tf.Tensor: id=11, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>]
[None, <tf.Tensor: id=11, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>]
[None, <tf.Tensor: id=11, shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.0>]
```

The following is the full code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
tfe = tf.contrib.eager

import os

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "6"
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

train_steps = 5

for i in range(train_steps):

    x = tf.contrib.eager.Variable(0.)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = tf.square(x)
        z = y + 2

    print(tape.gradient(z, [x,y]))
```

Any solution?

Comment: I'v tried running your example and gradients were computed for both variables. What tf version do you have?

Comment: @WunschPunsch Thanks. The problem turns to be that we should use the "persistent=True" argument in tf.GradientTape(). Also, we should call tape.gradient() for x and y separatedly instead of calling like tape.gradient(z, [x, y]).